# What is Initialization vector (IV)

Tags: initialization-vector, ecb, serpent

I am not the best cryptologer and therefore I have some questions so I learn more and get better. Heres the questions:

What is Initialization vector (IV)? MUST I use it or not?

Comment: What about reading about these things on your own (e.g. starting on wiki) and then coming back with more focused questions? This is too broad and shows no prior research.

Comment: Check the question again, I edited it.

Comment: What part of the Wikipedia article don't you understand?

Comment: @Gilles These sorts of attacks on perfectly reasonable beginner questions need to stop.  One of the reasons why the world is as insecure as it is is that people in the industry become hostile to anyone just starting out.  If this community is going to be helpful, it needs to accept questions of all skill levels, not just the extremely advanced ones that seem to be currently common.

Comment: @SteveSether This is not an attack and not a matter of skill level. Basic questions are fine. But “what is X?” when X can be looked up in an reference which is obviously discoverable, easily accessed and known to be reliable is at best a waste of time to copy the article from said reference. Questions like “I read the Wikipedia article and I don't understand this point: …” are perfectly fine, no matter how basic they are.

Comment: @Giles I'm sorry, I don't agree.  "RTFM" has been a cry of technical people for 30 years, and it's just as destructive now as it was then.  Your reply was a rather rude one, and discourages people from asking basic questions.  This community is filled with the kind of very difficult crypto questions that can only be answered by experts.  But yet software developers in general are totally perplexed by crypto, and don't understand it.  Someone left a similar rude reply to someone asking why he shouldn't use ECB mode in AES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Block Cipher Modes of Operation](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). IV is required for modes other than ECB, or your encryption will be extremely insecure. (Also note that ECB is insecure itself.)

Comment: Hey the down-voter, could you explain why you down-voted this answer? I could understand why this question is voted down, since it seems too basic. But IMHO, this answer gave a reference to where to check exactly (since it's a basic question, a reference is enough and more informative than a short explanation) and a short answer to the questioner's last question, so I don't think I deserve a down-vote.

Comment: Hi Haochen, welcome to Cryptography Stack Exchange. We (at Stack Exchange in general) prefer answers with a bit more explanation in the answer itself, instead of mainly a link to somewhere else on the Internet. If you could add some sentences about the function of the IV, this would improve your answer.

Comment: Thank you @PaŭloEbermann. I'll remember that. I was trying to choose among just giving a few sentences about what IV is, to copy and paste a large part of text from another source explaining the cipher mode, and IV (a lot of information is required in order to understand what IV does, and why it's needed), or just give an informative reference, so the questioner could check for good. The questioner is very likely already knowing what IV is, but asking further information, so I provided a link, and answered the last question directly. Well, I'll try to be more informative the next time.